# Recycler view scrolls without collapsing toobar

Tags: android

Recycler view scrolls without collapsing toobar. This is my Main layout.

```
<CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
       >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/collapp_bar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >
            <View
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
            <include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />
            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                >
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />


 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"

        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/selected_text_color"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/more_comment_color"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tab_layout"

        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        />

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the layout which I am setting in View Pager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

     <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recyler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/bg_listview" /></android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My Recycler view scrolls,even without collapsing toolbar sometimes.Alsothe scrolling is not smooth.In recyClerView of view pager i have a header item and then the list of items.Sometimes it get stuck at Header at top and need to pull it down.

Answer (score 2):

For every RecyclerView that is has a scrolling parent (such as ScrollView or NestedScrollView) you should disable nested scrolling like this:

```
yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

For your smoothing problem it seems that there is a bug with AppBarLayout and there are some libraries for fixing that. One that I know but I've never used is:
https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout